# Zend Framework - Access to View Helper from View

Tags: php, zend-framework, view-helpers

I have a problem with accessing a custom view helper in a view. Call the helper in the layout.phtml works perfectly.

**ZF Version: 1.11.2**

application.ini

```
resources.view[] =
```

Bootstrap:

```
protected function _initViewSettings()
{
    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');
    $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');

    $view->setScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/views/scripts/');
    $view->addHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/layouts/helpers/', 'Layout_Helper_');
    $view->addHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/views/helpers/', 'View_Helper_');

}
```

Helper: (application/views/helpers/Loader.php)

```
class View_Helper_Loader extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function loader()
    {
         $loader_html = '
             <div class="loading">
             <div class="bullet"></div>
             <div class="bullet"></div>
             <div class="bullet"></div>
             <div class="bullet"></div>
         </div>';

        return $loader_html;
    }
}
```

View:

```
<?php
    echo $this->loader();
?>
```

Error:

```
Plugin by name 'Loader' was not found in the registry; used paths: Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/
```

Why can't I use the helper in my view?

Comment: Zend Framework version?

Comment: What do u mean? The view init is already in my post :)

Comment: Can we see Bootstrap::_initView()?

Comment: Your view helper has the filename of Loader.php, should be LoaderTest.php

Comment: I don't see where the resource 'view' is defined??

Comment: ah just a mistake, sry. file- and functionnames are correct (updated my post). 

view resource in my application.ini ->  resources.view[] =

Comment: Tried in your version of ZF, cannot recreate this. But it looks like your helper paths are being clobbered somewhere.  Or the view is. Try `var_dump($this->getHelperPaths());` from the layout and the view, to check paths are registered, and triple check your paths, class names and filenames!  Are you manipulating the view anywhere else?  Any new Zend_View instances created?

Comment: Fixed it .. bad mistake of myself -.- thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

The problem were the following lines in my action:

```
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
```

I thought the result of my helper would be parsed into my view anyway. Bad mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try explicitly adding your view to the view renderer:

```
    $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper(
        'ViewRenderer'
    );
    $viewRenderer->setView($view);
```

I can't quite recreate your problem - having it work in the layout but not the view.

If I add a view resource to the application.ini, some of the wiring happens automagically for me in ZF 1.11.14, but if I create the view (new Zend_View) in the bootstrap as a resource I have to explicitly pass it to the view renderer.

Comment: added these lines to my bootstrap, but the error still appears :/